# Can I get a thread's stack address from pthread_self()

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads, x86-64

I want to get the stack address of a thread through some function to which we can pass **pthread_self()**. Is it possible? The reason I am doing this is because I want to write my own assigned thread identifier for a thread somewhere in its stack. I can write near the end of the stack (end of the stack memory and not the current stack address. We can ofcourse expect the application to not get to the bottom of the stack and therefore use space from there).

In other words, I want to use the thread stack for putting a kind of thread local variable there. So, do we have some function like the following provided by pthread?

```
stack_address = stack_address_for_thread( pthread_self() );
```

I can use the syntax for thread local variables by gcc for this purpose, but I'm in a situation where I can't use them.

Comment: How would you use such an address? The address of "the stack" is not very well-defined in C, since the language itself doesn't require a stack to be used. Even if you know the architecture uses stacks, the current frame for a thread will change all the time as the thread calls into and returns out of functions.

Comment: uwind, I agree, but like I said I can place my variable somewhere at the end of the stack. By end I mean the end of allocated stack. So If we have a stack of 1 MB, I can place it 1MB down. I know its hackish, but we can expect that an application is unlikely to get down to the bottom of the stack and few bytes there will remain free forever.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: still though, why? I like the question, but still wonder why you can't just store the data somewhere easier to access (and safer).

Comment: @Dan Fego, which safer place can we use? Any idea?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: If you want your own assigned thread identifier, you could have some structure/array on the heap that correlates `pthread_t`s with your own identifiers? Or am I perhaps missing the crux of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the bottom of the stack and give read/write permission to it with the following code.

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
void * stackaddr;
int * plocal_var;
size_t stacksize;

pthread_getattr_np(pthread_self(), &attr);
pthread_attr_getstack( &attr, &stackaddr, &stacksize );

printf( "stackaddr = %p, stacksize = %d\n", stackaddr, stacksize );

plocal_var = (int*)mmap( stackaddr, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
          MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0 );
// Now try to write something 
*plocal_var = 4;
```

and then you can get the thread ID, with the function **get_thread_id()** shown below. Note that calling `mmap` with size 4096 has the effect of pushing the boundary of the stack by 4096, that is why we subtract 4096 when getting the local variable address.

```
int get_thread_id()
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    char * stackaddr;
    int * plocal_var;
    size_t stacksize;

    pthread_getattr_np(pthread_self(), &attr);
    pthread_attr_getstack( &attr, (void**)&stackaddr, &stacksize );

    //printf( "stackaddr = %p, stacksize = %d\n", stackaddr, stacksize );

    plocal_var = (int*)(stackaddr - 4096);

    return *plocal_var;
}
```

Comment: If you can't use thread-locals, what makes you believe that `pthread_getattr_np` *will* work?

Comment: This is really hacky and will rely on a specific data layout of your stack. Ways for thread specific storage are provided in the standards and by the tools, use them.

Comment: By using MAP_FIXED you run the significant risk of running over anything that happened to be mapped there. This is an imperfect solution at best.

Comment: ... but it is a good gist giving an interesting draft mechanism for own managed id and other things ... and it does say 'linux' in the tags ... i found it because i am doing something similar. Can reserve a large space with a previous mmap PROT_NONE and then set the thread (or cloned CLONE_VM process in my case) stacks to be specifically part of that area (before creation of each thread) by a mmap over a shorter MAP_FIXED area of the originally mapped large area. Then no risk of running over anything ... it would also be easy to port it to eg OSX using eg pthread_get_stackaddr_np ... etc

Answer (score 6):

Probably it's better to use `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_key_getspecific` and let the implementation worry about those details.

A good example of usage is here:

[pthread_key_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_key_create.html)

Edit: I should clarify -- I'm suggesting you use the libpthread provided method of creating thread-local information, instead of rolling your own by pushing something onto the end of the stack where it's possible your information could be lost.

Answer (score 2):

With GCC, it is simpler to declare your thread local variables with [__thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html) keyword, like

```
  __thread int i;
  extern __thread struct state s;
  static __thread char *p;
```

That is GCC specific (but I'll guess `clang` has it also, and the newest C++ & future C standards have something similar), but less brittle than pointers hacks based upeon `pthread_self()` (and should be a bit faster, but less portable, than `pthread_key_getsspecific`, as [suggested by Denniston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8729641/841108))

But I would really like you to give more context and motivation in your questions.

Comment: Yes Basile, I know how to create thread local variables in gcc but like I said in my question, I can't use them here.

Comment: You should explain why you cannot use them. And you should explain why your solution is better (I don't think so).

Comment: thread local storage `_Thread_local` is also a new feature that comes with C11 and it is practically equivalent to this gcc extension. So using this feature in gcc is future proof.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write my own assigned thread identifier for a thread

There are multiple ways to achieve that. The most obvious one:

```
__thread int my_id;
```

> I can use the syntax for thread local variables by gcc for this purpose, but I'm in a situation where I can't use them.

You need to explain *why* you can't use thread-locals. Chances are high that other solutions, such as `pthread_getattr_np`, wouldn't work either.