# Base address of thread stack in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, stack, pthreads

I have a question. In linux C programming, if we create a thread using pthread, and we can get its tid by `pthread_self()`.
Is there a way to obtain the base address of this thread simply(Using some API from pthread)?
Thank you!

Comment: I guess you can use `pthread_getaddr_np` followed by `pthread_attr_getstack`.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729384/can-i-get-a-threads-stack-address-from-pthread-self

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use `pthread_getaddr_np` (not necessarily portable, seems to work with glibc and musl) and `pthread_attr_getstack`

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE //for pthread_getattr_np
#include <pthread.h>

void* thread_main(void* args) {
    //your code here
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &thread_main, NULL);
    pthread_attr_t attrs;
    pthread_getattr_np(thread, &attrs);
    void* stack_ptr;
    size_t stack_size;
    pthread_attr_getstack(&attrs, &stack_ptr, &stack_size);
    //`stack_ptr` now points to the base address of the spawned thread's stack
    ...
}
```

If you try to avoid the call to `pthread_getaddr_np`, you may get unexpected results. If you use the dafault value of stack address, `pthread_create()` ignores it and picks a suitable stack address (on linux, gnu libc and musl libc).

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE //for pthread_getattr_np
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* thread_main(void* args) {
    //your code here
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    void* stack_ptr;
    size_t stack_size;
    pthread_attr_getstack(&attrs, &stack_ptr, &stack_size);
    printf("default stack address:\t%x\n", stack_ptr);

    pthread_create(&thread, &attrs, &thread_main, NULL);
    pthread_getattr_np(thread, &attrs);
    pthread_attr_getstack(&attrs, &stack_ptr, &stack_size);
    //`stack_ptr` now points to the base address of the spawned thread's stack
    printf("real stack address:\t%x\n", stack_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
default stack address:  0
real stack address: d385a000
```

Answer (score -4):

It is `0x00000000`. Surprisingly..

Comment: You may have be mislead by the fact that `pthread_attr_init()` gives a default `pthread_attr_getstackaddr()` value of 0; however `pthread_create()` interprets a value of 0 here to mean "put the stack wherever you want". I didn't find this information in the documentation anywhere, but through experimentation, see my answer.